# Volume using VB Script in ArcMap field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, vbscript, if-else

I am trying to compute the volume of the area given certain condition. I wrote the following VBScript code, however I am getting error that it has failed to do so.

Can anyone look into it and suggest a way forward?

```
if [Area_Ha]<=70 Then 
 [Volume__De]=2.85* [Area_Ha]^1.22
elseif  [Area_Ha] >70 Then
 [Volume__De] =7.1* [Area_Ha]+9.97
endif
```

The picture of the attribute table is attached.

[image]

---

Attached is the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need to bring your calculated field in the return part of the function:

Try:

```
if [Area_Ha] <=70
then [Area_Ha]^1.22 * 2.85
else
([Area_Ha]+9.97)*7.1
end if
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the field calculator on that given field you can just use this with codeblock enabled. Tested with Volume field as a float and it works:

```
if [Area_Ha]<=70 then 
  result = 2.85 *([Area_Ha]^1.22)
elseif  [Area_Ha] >70 then
  result = 7.1* ([Area_Ha]+9.97)
end if
```

Then:
      `Volume_De = result`

In python I think you're not allowed to use the "^" so use math.pow instead:

```
def vol(Area_Ha):
  if Area_Ha <= 70:
     return 2.85*(math.pow(Area_Ha,1.22))
  else:
     return 7.1 * ((Area_Ha) + 9.97)
```

Then:
`vol(!Area_Ha!)`